# Angular Material tab height

Tags: angular, angular-flex-layout

I am trying to have a full page Angular Material tab which has tabs which are full height and have a centered message. I have created [this stakblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fad56q) as I can't get it to work. The fxFill's don't seem to Fill and I am not sure if this is an issue with the Flexbox layout or Angular Material. I don't want to force a height as within each tab as that seems to defeat the point of flexible layouts.

Am sure its simple but help a poor confused developer who is used to Bootstrap grid :)

**UPDATE**
Adding *height: calc(100vh - 100px);* to the parent div and then also to the tall.component div makes things work but ***surely this is a bad solution***

Comment: One reason it can be a bad solution is that `vh` is pretty much a fixed value on mobile devices with or without the onscreen keyboard, or toolbars which appear and disappear differently across platforms. Be cautious of this and that if you expect `vh` to be truly dynamic it may not be. % actually often works better here.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

In order to fill the page, the page needs to fill the window:

**styles.css**

```
body, html{
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
```

The app component needs to fill the body:

**app.component.css**

```
:host{
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
}
```

By default the wrappers of the content within the tabs are not filling the tab's height so we will fix this:

**styles.css**

```
.mat-tab-body-wrapper{
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

We also need to have the `mat-tab-group` fill the height, its parent needs to fill the height too, so we will give an id to both the wrapper and the tab-group.

**app.component.html**

```
<div id="wrapper"> <!-- give it an id -->
    <div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutGap="16px" fxFill>
        <div fxFlex="20">
            <p>Fun Sidebar</p>
        </div>
        <div fxFlex="80" fxFill>
            <mat-tab-group id="tab-group"> <!-- give it an id -->
                <mat-tab label="Summary">
                    <div fxFlex style="padding: 16px;">
                        <div class="mat-display-2">Hello</div>
                        <p>Lorem ipsulem</p>
                    </div>
                </mat-tab>
                <mat-tab label="Tall content">
                    <app-tall-component></app-tall-component>
                </mat-tab>
            </mat-tab-group>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**app.component.css**

```
#wrapper{
  padding: 16px; 
  min-height: 100%; 
  height: 100%; 
  box-sizing: border-box;/*new*/
}
#tab-group{
  height: 100%;
}
#tab-group mat-tab-body {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

---

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-awamwn?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: Thanks - Works perfectly - Although when I translate to my code the mat-tab-body-wrapper does not have the style : flex-grow: 1 which is being automatically applied in our code. Odd - Without it - your code doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks! Read again :) there is a section about it, you have to add it a rule to set it to flex in your styles.scss

Comment: Sorry missed that as I added it to the component scss instead :P

Comment: there is a native solution by setting dynamicHeight input to true

Comment: If not using fxLayout, can we implement with pure css flex?

Answer (score 13):

This is worked for me to assign dynamic value for height.

```
:host ::ng-deep .mat-tab-body-wrapper {
  height: 600px;

}

:host ::ng-deep .mat-tab-body.mat-tab-body-active {
  height: 600px;

}
```

Comment: Thanks, I just specified height: 100% and it worked for me.

Comment: Where does this css go?

Comment: The css file that you have specified to style Material Tab

Answer (score 8):

According to [Angular docs](https://material.angular.io/components/tabs/overview#dynamic-height): you need to set the **dynamicHeight** input to true `<mat-tab-group dynamicHeight>`

> By default, the tab group will not change its height to the height of the currently active tab. To change this, set the dynamicHeight input to true. The tab body will animate its height according to the height of the active tab.

Comment: Not working for me in angular 11. Can you show a stackblitz?