# How to make mat-tab occupy entire available space

Tags: angular-material, mat-tab

I have angular app where I am using mat-tabs, I need to make inner element to occupy the entire available space.

```
<mat-tab-group dynamicHeight="true">
  <mat-tab label="Test Tab 1">
    <mat-tab-group dynamicHeight="true">
      <mat-tab label="Test Child Tab 1">
          <div class="h-full bg-yellow-400 text-center align-middle"> Split Container </div>
      </mat-tab>
      <mat-tab label="Test Child Tab 2"></mat-tab>
    </mat-tab-group>
  </mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="Test Tab 2">
  </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

I tried solution suggested in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50722183/angular-material-tab-height) However it did not work.
I am not using material layout. here is the [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uf6lmz?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftall.component.html) to stackblitz that shows the issue. I forked it out from aforementioned stackoveflow question and removed layout usage.

Any tips are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
<mat-tab-group mat-stretch-tabs>
 <mat-tab label="One"> One </mat-tab>
 <mat-tab label="Two"> Two </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```